# How can I connect Android to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: android, .net, json, model-view-controller, connect

How can I connect android to mvc ? For example I want to open my camera via google chrome, how can I control it ? People telling me to use json is that true ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of. Looks to me that you should explore the world of APIs in general as you are not too familiar with them. By the way a REST API is a good way to go, but you'll need a platform, a "server" to do it.
Then you will be able to control your device from a remote one.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a mess.

It sounds like: I want to send a rocket to the mars people telling me that I need oxygen is that true?

Below I'll try to clarify what you need and what you want:

1. You need your own android application that can open camera by
   server application request.
2. You need your own server side ASP.NET application.
3. When somebody opens a web page on your ASP.NET your server app should some how to establish a connection with an instance of your android application and tell it to start capturing of media-stream from the camera.
4. You want to send media stream from your android camera to a desktop browser

Answer:

You can use JSON as well as any other data-interchange format at point 3.
But keep in mind that your data should be transferred by some data transfer protocol - most probably HTTP.

At point 4 to work with media in a browser have a look to the WebRTC.